# Local Interconnect Network(LIN) default status

Tags: protocol

How does slave identification takes place in LIN protocol by the master ?

What is the default status of a LIN bus ?

How are collisions avoided in LIN ?

What is the role of Sporadic frame ?

Comment: The question you really need to ask is "How do I use Google?" Then you could have found [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Interconnect_Network) by yourself.

Comment: Not even one of the above are found in Google mr.Finbarrrrrrr

Comment: You've proved my point. Try just typing "LIN bus" into Google. Without the double quotes.

Comment: my question is nor introduction to LIN bus

Comment: I know, sometimes you have to actually read an article to find the answers you're looking for. What a chore, eh? I can see the answer to one of your questions in that article straight away and I haven't even read it.

Comment: Spent two days reading LIN. could not find answers to the above questions !!

Comment: "How are collisions avoided in LIN ?"

From the first section in the Wikipedia article I gave you the link to: "Because all communications are initiated by the master it is not necessary to implement a collision detection"

Comment: @Finbarr Have you heard about the case of even triggered frame ?? if not please click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Interconnect_Network)

Comment: I'd never even heard of LIN until yesterday. But if you mean event triggered frame, I just looked at the document and it still says it's done under control of the bus master so still no need for collision avoidance.

Comment: That is what my question is how does the master control it ?
@Finbarr

Answer (score 0):

your questions are good enough and are logic because they are not clearly answered in the iso. The default status of the lin bus is sleep. However the master can either do sporadic or do continous quering. Sporadic means it wakes up the bus and queries for a short time some device and sleeps again.
Collision is avoided by the master schedule tables. [Specs from the Lin Consortium](https://assets.vector.com/cms/content/know-how/lin/LIN-Spec_2.2_Rev_A.PDF)